# Regarding Transfer of rows between a Datagridview to a Listview

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I transfer selected rows from a Datagridview to a listview? 
(Sorry Guys I messed up in asking this previously the wrong way!!)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)  
    {  
    lvt = new ListViewItem();  
    lvt.SubItems.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());  
    lvt.SubItems.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());  
    lvt.SubItems.Add(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());  
    lvt.SubItems.Add(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());  
    listView1.Items.Add(lvt);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not `name`, it should be `SubItems`

```
    ListViewItem lvItem;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {

        lvItem = new ListViewItem();
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Item"].Value.ToString());
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Cost"].Value.ToString());
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Manufacturer"].Value.ToString());
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Quanlity"].Value.ToString());
        // ...
    }
```

or

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {

        lvItem = new ListViewItem(row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Item"].Value.ToString());
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Cost"].Value.ToString());
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Manufacturer"].Value.ToString());
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Quanlity"].Value.ToString());
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks John i think this wil work.. Somehow I had my mind confused in this, Now i can figure out... Thanks..

Comment: Unfortunately nope... It does not even budge a little. No Exceptions whatsoever :(, How will it matter if I included   row.cells["ID"].value.tostring(); in my code? because in my VS 2010 the listview continues to remain empty.. :(. does it work on your VS c#?